# Use of const in a Javascript class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, constants

In my JS component class, I have the following code at the top;

```
const {
    getOwner
} = Ember;
```

What exactly does it mean ? Is the purpose to avoid code repetition ?

Comment: What exactly are you asking about? The [`const` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) or the [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)?

Comment: It's just a way of getting 'getOwner' value from 'Ember' object

Answer (score 1):

This is a new feature of JS present in ES6.
This is known as object destructure.

If you have an object like this.

```js
 const obj = { name: 'Stack Overflow' };
 
 const { name } = obj;
 
 console.log(name);
```

You can take a reference -> 
[Here for Destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

And yeah about the `const` keyword.
The const keyword is used to declare a constant variable which is going to be same for the whole

and for const -> [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)

```js
try{ 
  const a = 10;
  a =12;
}catch(e){
  console.log(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Is the purpose to avoid code repetition*.

I don't really think so.

It is just a [**`destructing assignment`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to assign `Ember` object's `getOwner` property to variable  `getOwner` in your code. And [**`const`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) is there to make sure it is not overwritten by some other assignment